# error "Test failed: Main server ADSrv" when integrating directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to integrate GLPI with Active Directory. I'm using windows XAMPP V3.2.2 and GLPI 0.90.1. While setting up the LDAP Directory, I'm getting an error "Test failed: Main server ADSrv".  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to know the answer for sure. It could be a hundred different things, but I'll just take a stab and guess that your "RootDN" should be: `cn=prahallad.kulkarni,ou=UserAccounts,dc=rezblr,dc=local`

instead of

`cn=prahallad.kulkarni,dc=rezblr,dc=local`.

I highly doubt that your user account is not in a container or OU of any kind.

Reference:
http://wiki.glpi-project.org/doku.php?id=en:ldap

Comment: That RootDN is definitely one issue, but as you alluded, probably not the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

instead of cn=prahallad.kulkarni,dc=rezblr,dc=local ,

try to replace it with :

Domaine/administrator ,

and fill the password with the Domain admin password account.

worked for me...